Kafka mirror maker 2 copy topic as avro not bytes
i have a kafka cluster in the US and i would like to replicate a topic onto an EU cluster. these 2 cluster share the same schema registry. i snapshot a table and can see the messages as avro on the NA server i can see the schema on the registry is correct. I then set up a mirror maker connector with the following config
{
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
    "admin.timeout.ms": "300000",
    "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "IP:9092",//same as the first IP in target.cluster.bootstrap.servers
    "topics": "test",
    "source.cluster.alias": "NA",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "IP:9092",
    "target.cluster.alias": "",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "IP:9092,IP:9092,IP:9092",
    "replication.policy.separator": "-",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://IP:8085",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://IP:8085"
} 

that creates a topic on the other end as NA-test, as expected
my issue is then when i go to sink the data, the schema is not structured and only contains "bytes".
with this set up using the same schema registry, is it possible to transfer the data as avro ? i have tried writing to the target topic directly by setting the alias to blank and the separator. but that results in this error
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Failed to access Avro data from topic test : Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "test-key"; error code: 409

does anyone have a solution so that the schemas match when using mirror maker ?

if i change the avro convertor to org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter it stops making the schema in the registry and only makes the topic

i found a solution for this
swapping the avro convertor to org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
then setting "source.cluster.alias" and "replication.policy.separator" to ""
allowed the messages to be written to the target topic in avro
which allowed the sink connector to work
